# How to save a stretched image?

Tags: iphone

How can I save a stretched image?

I have a small(50 X 50) image, that I have stretched  while displaying it on a UIImageView (by choosing scaletofit mode.) Now I need to fetch & save that stretched image. 
         I have tried by using UIImageView's image property, but it gives me original image not that stretched image.

So, do you have any idea how to solve this problem? If then please help me or guide me or at-least give me a hint.

Hoping for your reply.........

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an image by copying the bit map of the view's CGContext (core graphic context). This has been asked on stackoverflow before but I can't find the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render your UIImageView into a graphic context you create :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourUIImageView.frame.size);
yourUIImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

//get the PNG representation of the UIImage (but you could do the same with JPEG
NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);
//then save it to a file
[myData writeToFile:thePathToWriteYourFileAsNSString atomically:YES];